# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/a/a/a/a;

Tags: android, office-2007

I use OliveDocLibrary  to display  DOC, XLS and PPT,when I add OlivePhone-OliveOffice-excel-android-4.0.3-universal-trial-1.0.2.jar,it can work, can display xls;but when I  add olivephone-sdk-ppt-android-1.6-universial-trial-1.0.0.jar,it error:
[2013-05-16 18:51:08 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/a/a/a/a;
[2013-05-16 18:51:08 - OfficeTest] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/a/a/a/a;

I think  maybe the jar has same class,i want to know how to solve problem,please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Recently the android sdk had changed its strategy and required the jar's were in the android project and libraries to be used.

But now this strategy changed again, and the jar's only need to be in the project library that uses them.